# Why is the orderBy method in my PHP code not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote this PHP code in Laravel 5 and orderBy won't work.

```
Route::get('/products',function (){$products= DB::table('products')->get();
return view('products.index',compact('products'));});

Route::get('/products/{id}',function ($id){$product= DB::table('products')->find($id);
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));});
```

and index.blade.php code is

```
 <div><a href={{"/products/".$product->id}}>{{$product->name}}</a></div>
```

and show.blade.php code is:

```
 <h1>{{$product->name}}</h1>
 <p> {{$product->description}}</p>
```

Comment: Look's odd you orderBy one field, because you're find one product of the table. Maybe DB::table('products')->orderBy('name','desc')->get(); makes more sense

Comment: thank you for answar I edit my question and complete with full changed code

Comment: @TohidDa don't edit your question after answers unless you are ONLY providing more context.  You completely removed your orderBy call...

Answer (score 3):

When you use `find()` it will return only 1 registry. So, order by has no effect.

If the `$id` is present in more than 1 row, then you should use `where` and `get()`

```
$product= DB::table('products')->where('id','=',$id)->orderBy('name','desc')->get();
```

So, if you add order by, it should work:

```
Route::get('/products',function (){
    $products= DB::table('products')->orderBy('name','desc')->get();
    return view('products.index',compact('products'));
});
```